# How Do You Specify Where The Gradle Wrapper Installs Gradle?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have an off the shelf application that ships a version of gradle with it. It also has scripts that are hard coded to set GRADLE_HOME to this location.

I want to zip up this dir, put it in nexus and replace it with the gradle wrapper.

How do I configure the gradle wrapper to download this zip from nexus and extract it to a specific location in the project?

EDIT: In the gradle-wrapper.properties I have
`distributionPath=wrapper/gradle`

However, I end up with it being unzipped to
`...\wrapper\gradle\gradle-2.3-bin\8gn7esgljqyucijpbynjk93oc\gradle-2.3`

How do I get it to unzip to the path I specified and not to the subdirs?

Answer (score 3):

The location to which Gradle gets unpacked is a combination of the `distributionBase` **and** `distributionPath` properties in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

The location specified by `distributionPath` will always be considered as relative to `distributionBase`. The **only** available values for `distributionPath` are `GRADLE_USER_HOME` and `PROJECT`. Even when using `PROJECT` the wrapper will still generate the folder structure you see above.

If you want to control this more precisely I'd suggest not relying on the wrapper to do this and instead add a task to your build specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Upvotes for the answer, just not the answer I wanted to hear :(